# Error in Trying to Use Python Module

Tags: python, macos, module

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability) module in a project, but can't figure out how to use it.

What I've tried:

1. Downloaded the module as a ZIP file.
2. Unzipped that file, giving me the directory structure I saw in the GitHub page.
3. Opened up Terminal, and navigated to the directory with `setup.py` in it.
4. Ran the command `sudo python setup.py install`
5. This seemed to run fine, as I get a message saying "Finished processing dependencies"

Now, when I go into PyCharm (the IDE I'm using) and try to run `import readability` I get an error saying `ImportError: No module named 'readability'`

Possible reason for failure:

- I specified to PyCharm that I am using a Python 3 interpreter. Would Terminal by default install in the 2.x Python directory?
- Does the location of my PyCharm .py file matter?

Comment: What does `python --version` output?

Comment: Did you restart PyCharm?  It might not have picked up the changes immediately.  Can you import it from the terminal, not just from your IDE?

Comment: Does it work in the python shell? Do you have one or multiple versions of python?

Comment: Run the setup.py with the same interpreter PyCharm uses.

Comment: Python version outputs 2.7.2. I can import readability from the Terminal. I have two versions of python apparently.

Comment: Running the install command with python3 gives me this error: ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

Do I have install setuptools as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main error was running the python commands in Terminal under version 2.7.2. By using the keyword python3 instead of python, I was able to force Terminal to use the correct version. I also needed to install setuptools.